# Get values from redis-cli.exe --stat

Tags: powershell, redis

I use Redis 3.2.100 on Windows and for monitoring have to get values from 'redis-cli --stat' with the help of Powershell, but I can not do it because it go on without stop. Do you know any commands to get this info in one line and stop command line?

Comment: Run with a timeout maybe https://gist.github.com/lazywinadmin/e7350ee7df6bc30f2ce5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `redis-cli INFO` at regular intervals and extract the required information.

`redis-cli INFO` includes all metrics like SERVER, CLIENTS, MEMORY, PERSISTENCE, STATS, REPLICATION, CLUSTER,CPU, KEYSPACE etc.

To get individual metrics use `redis-cli INFO <METRIC NAME>` example: `redis-cli INFO SERVER`.

Also you can use [redis-stat](https://github.com/junegunn/redis-stat) which internally uses INFO command.